# External trigger (PostgreSQL) for Django application

Tags: django, triggers

I have a difficulty with my Django application: I have two databases, and I would like that when an instance is added to PostgreSQL, a Django function is triggered to work on the default database. Could you list the steps to follow? Thank you.

I have created a trigger in the external database, but I can't get Django to react despite implementing pgtrigger.

---